# XAF Devexpress Form Label Type Change

Tags: xaf

How to customize the appearance of forms belonging to classes in xaf. For example how to change the label font and other properties (except for special forms).[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywmG7.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the appearance of your labels as described in this document [How to: Apply HTML Formatting to Windows Forms XAF UI Elements](https://documentation.devexpress.com/eXpressAppFramework/113130/Task-Based-Help/Application-Model/How-to-Apply-HTML-Formatting-to-Windows-Forms-XAF-UI-Elements)

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic, fine grained control use https://documentation.devexpress.com/eXpressAppFramework/113286/Concepts/Extra-Modules/Conditional-Appearance/Conditional-Appearance-Module-Overview

To change font/size globally use https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A2761/how-to-change-the-font-of-all-devexpress-controls